# flipping card bug on IOS

Tags: iphone, css, css-animations

i just hosted a small portfolio via github pages, and I tried to use media query to make it work on various device size.
The portfolio section includes these flipping card which i've been told are bogus on IOs devices when using chrome.
In fact it seems the back face are diplayed mirror on the Y axis.

I tried to debug by using CrossBrowser but without success.

[Here's](https://github.com/koop4/koop4.github.io) the repo with the code,
[Here's](https://koop4.github.io/#portfolio) a link to the bogus section.

Here some code should be enough to reproduce the issue (but i would still suggest to consider the repo code since i could miss something here)

html

```
<figure class="fig-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div img class="front face"  style="background-image: url('http://img.youtube.com/vi/x10dBwZFi2Q/0.jpg');"></div>
    <div class="back face">
      <p><b>Location:</b> loc</p>
      <p><b class="text-medium-big">Description: </b> desc</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</figure>
```

css

```
figure{
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.fig-container {
  max-width: 450px;
  min-height: 160px;
  /* horizontal center*/
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.card {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 250px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.fig-container:hover .card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 17px;  
}

.face.front {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.face.back {
  display: block;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.5em;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 1.5;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Anyone is able to see the bug and understand what it could be the problem?